# simply solve not showing doble solutions

Tags: python, function, sympy

I need SymPy to show all the solutions of a function, duplicated if it is the case.
In other words I would need that:

```
x=sym.symbols('x')
sym.solve(x**2, x)
```

returned

```
[0,0]
```

while it actually returns only:

```
[0]
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is the function always a polynomial?

Comment: yes, it is actually the determinant of a parametric matrix

Comment: In case you aren't interested in complex roots, `sym.real_roots(x**2)`  would return the real roots, default with multiplicity. [docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polytools.real_roots)

Comment: @JohanC Thank you! in case of real roots it works exactly as I need. Now the question is: is there a way to achieve the same with complex roots as well, considering that I know before hand the power of the polynomial? To be more precise: I do not know the coefficients of the several terms of the polynomial. I should calculate it solving symbolically the determinant of a matrix but this is a waste of resources. However I know the polynomial grade, which is equal to the number of rows of the matrix. Is this info enough to find all the solutions, both real and complex with moltiplicyty?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the roots of a polynomial along with their multiplicity. That is given by the `roots` function if you specify `multiple=True`:

```
In [6]: roots(x**2, multiple=True)                                                                                                
Out[6]: [0, 0]

In [7]: roots(x**2 + 1, multiple=True)                                                                                            
Out[7]: [ⅈ, -ⅈ]
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polyroots.roots

There are other functions such as `real_roots` to get the real roots and `nroots` to get numerical approximations of the roots depending on exactly what you want to do.